# How to properly include IBM EJB mappings using Maven

Tags: maven, websphere, ejb-3.0

I have a Maven EJB project that is meant to be installed on a WAS8.5 server. Everything compiles up to the EAR fine, however, when I try to deploy the application the MDB mappings are not auto-filled in. I extract the jar (inside the ear) and I see...

```
--META-INF
----ejb-jar.xml
----ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml
```

So why isn't the mapping being picked up? Is there a configuration I need in my Plugin?

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <!-- generate manifest file properly -->
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

UPDATE:

This looks like it is more of a problem with ibm-web-bnd.xml. I have confirmed that is in the final war.

Update for question...

I am using activation spec, as far as I can tell these are delcared fine in the ibm-ejb-bnd.xml of the ejb project. I can see them there in the ear. However, it still doesn't work. Also, I have an ear built by the old system and here and I have found no real differences in the following files...

- application.xml
- ibm-web-bnd.xml
- ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml

I have also glanced over the web.xml and MANIFEST files and don't see anything.

Finally another weird note is when I try to install the maven generated one I see...

[image]

However, when I try to upload the Ant (previous build) one I see these options

[image]

UPDATE: Per comment

I added these files to a folder called new and one called old.

```
~/My Documents/tmp/file
$ ls old/
application.xml  ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml  ibm-web-ext.xml
ejb-jar.xml      ibm-web-bnd.xml
```

I then diffed the two folders, here is the outcome...

```
diff new/application.xml old/application.xml
5c5
<       <module id="Module_1352494482335">^M
---
>       <module id="Module_1276803943498">^M
```

Comment: What kind of MDB mappings are you using? Listener ports? activation specs?

Comment: Can you please confirm that the files are identical? also, can you confirm that the files' extensions in both cases is "xml", and not "xmi"?

Comment: see my new update, they seem to be similar I will try to make exact...

Comment: So you're telling us that all of the differences between the two modules amount to that Module ID attribute? Look again. :-)

Comment: Not sure again are you asking me to triple check, or am I missing something obvious? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If the two EARs are completely identical except for the module ID in one of the deployment descriptors, then the deployment flow (through the WAS admin console) should look exactly the same.

Comment: Right I agree but I have no idea what other file would change that, it does appear that the deps are in the root instead of lib, Also I don't have some entries for deps in my Manifest because of the new format.

Comment: So I do see that the new has line breaks in the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml, could those be the Windows line breaks? Do I need to remove them?

Comment: Been looking at it more, still haven't found any differences, is there any other file that could be responsible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with so many things my resolution was unscientific. However, this SEEMED to work for me....

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <property name="was6.home" value="C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer" />
                            <property name="user.install.root" value="${was6.home}" />   
                            <path id="was.classpath">
                                <fileset dir="${was6.home}/lib">
                                    <include name="webservices.jar" />
                                    <include name="wsprofile.jar" />
                                    <include name="j2ee.jar" />
                                    <include name="ffdc.jar" />
                                    <include name="wsdl4j.jar" />
                                    <include name="bootstrap.jar" />
                                    <include name="commons-logging-api.jar" />
                                    <include name="commons-discovery.jar" />
                                    <include name="ras.jar" />
                                    <include name="wsexception.jar" />
                                    <include name="emf.jar" />
                                    <include name="classloader.jar" />
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset dir="${was6.home}/dev">
                                    <include name="was_public.jar" />
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset dir="${was6.home}/plugins">
                                    <include name="com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar" />
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset dir="${was6.home}/java/jre/lib">
                                    <include name="xml.jar" />
                                    <include name="ibmorb.jar" />
                                    <include name="ibmorbapi.jar" />
                                </fileset>
                            </path>
                            <path id="wsejbdeploy.path">
                                <path refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                                <fileset dir="${was6.home}/java/jre/lib">
                                    <include name="xml.jar" />
                                    <include name="ibmorb.jar" />
                                    <include name="ibmorbapi.jar" />
                                </fileset>
                            </path>
                            <taskdef name="wasEjbDeploy" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WsEjbDeploy" 
                                 classpathref="was.classpath" />

                            <echo> 
                                Hello World: FYI
                                project.name=${project.name}
                                project.artifactId=${project.artifactId}
                                project.groupId=${project.groupId}
                                project.version=${project.version}
                                project.packaging=${project.packaging}
                                project.description=${project.description}
                            </echo>

                            <delete dir="${project.build.directory}/ejbdeply-working" />
                            <wasEjbDeploy 
                                inputJar="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar" 
                                outputJar="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-OUTPUT.jar" 
                                wasHome="${was6.home}" 
                                classpathref="wsejbdeploy.path"
                                workingDirectory="${project.build.directory}/ejbdeply-working"
                                keepGenerated="true"
                                failonerror="true"
                                trace="true" />

                            <move file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${version}.jar" 
                                tofile="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${version}-INPUT.jar"  />

                            <move file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${version}-OUTPUT.jar" 
                               tofile="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${version}.jar"  />

                            <echo> **** Task WsEJBDeploy Complete! **** </echo>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, I am having similar issue. Is there any update other than using antrun plgunin?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use was6-maven-plugin.

It does exactly the same thing (it generates a ant file using Websphere custom tags like wsejbdeploy and then invokes it using Websphere ws_ant utility) but it calculates for you most of the attributes and paths.

There is also an ant task named wsDefaultBindings (see link above) that you can use directly or through was6-maven-plugin that can help you to create the bindings using an external file

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2Fapidocs%2Findex.html&com%2Fibm%2Fwebsphere%2Fant%2Ftasks%2FInstallApplication.html

Regards